# Acknowledgements: Dr or Prof?

Tags: presentations

I am presenting my research work at a conference. In my poster, I am crediting my research advisor. For anonymity purposes, say his name is John Smith. He is a PhD so he is often addressed Dr. Smith but he is a professor at my university so his students call him Prof. Smith. In my poster, should I credit him as Dr. John Smith or Prof. John Smith?

Comment: I doubt it actually matters, but if you're concerned, ask your advisor himself.

Comment: @R_Kapp He is out of town and has no access to e-mail within the time I have to finish.

Comment: You might get better answers on academia.se. Not saying you're off topic here, just pointing out a site that might be useful

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks for that info! Didn't know that site existed. :)

Comment: @KateGregory IMO, most of the answers here are wrong so, yes, better answers would definitely be had at [academia.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use "Professor".

Why?  Because that is your adviser's official title at your university.  It's a recognised "rank", and so he should be addressed as such, especially if you are introducing him in the capacity of your work at your university.

Comment: Be careful with this though because "professor" may be different than "assistant professor" vs "associate professor" etc. Academia often cares about title a lot more. I'd suggest just asking to avoid any potential issues.

Comment: To supplement this answer *Dr*. is an exclusive group of people.  *Professor * is a more exclusive group than *Dr.* and part of the reason you should go with *Professor*.

Comment: This is backward.  In the academia I'm familiar with, professors are called "Professor Smith" if and only if they don't have a PhD.  It's actually mildly insulting to call them "Professor Smith": It implies they're not fully qualified.

Also, it's not true that it's a "recognized rank".  Most people you call "Professors" are not actually "Professors".  They're usually "Assistant Professors" (if they're not tenured yet), or "Associate Professors" (if they're tenured).  "Full Professors" are a minority, the most senior of the tenured group.  

Call your advisor "Dr".   It's safe and accurate.

Comment: I've been to many academic conferences and never seen titles used when crediting somebody.

Comment: I would add that if you are going to capitalize and they are an assistant or associate then that should be included as that is the official title.  In the US it is hard to get a full professorship at a major (or even minor) university.  And for professor I would use Prof. as it is the standard abbreviation - at least in the US.

Comment: @iayork - at my university (and I'm sure most others in the UK), professor was a role and title given to senior lecturers in a department, and all the professors I knew there had PhD's. We called them Professor (or "Dan" ;) ) - calling them Dr would have been impolite as it implied ignorance of their position as senior staff.

Comment: Clearly very location-dependent; my experience has been in the US and Canada.

Comment: @Frisbee No, you'd never address or refer to somebody as "Assistant/Associate Professor Frisbee". Those are job titles, not honorifics.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well you would not.  And Frisbee is not my real name so I would be addressed by that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well you would not. And Frisbee is not my real name so I would be addressed by that.  And the question is credit on paper - not address.

Answer (score 7):

Best answer: Ask them how they would like to be referred to.

> "Absolute is the right of any man to spell his name 'Jones' and have it pronounced 'Smith'."

If unable to do that, I'd use whatever form they last published under, which they presumably found acceptable. Or contact their department and ask if anyone there knows.

Comment: That is the best answer, except that OP has said that the professor is out and inaccessible until after the deadline.

Comment: @KentAnderson: Expanded answrr to address that case. When possible, research beats guessing.

Comment: What's the source for that quote? It's rather good.

Answer (score 4):

**Another Short Answer:** Use "Dr." or "..., PhD."

Acknowledging the PhD is the safest route if your concern is avoiding his being offended.

If a professor holds a doctorate degree, he or she will not be offended if you acknowledge it with the "..., PhD." suffix. However, if you do not acknowledge it, there may be some who would be offended, especially given that you're working in an academic setting, and there is some level of prestige among their peers involved in your work. So, it's safer to acknowledge the PhD.

If the professor does not hold the degree, then "Professor" is the right choice, obviously.

Comment: When I did my PhD, my adviser had a PhD but held the title of "Professor".   She _always_ introduced herself as "Professor", which was a ranked title.

Comment: Hi @JaneS, Fair enough. However, this is in a context of printed/published work, where PhD or Dr would be more appropriate. It may be a cultural thing - in the US, at least, PhD's often come with a bit of ego, especially when referenced in an academic setting.

Comment: I guess that over here, you can't even _have_ the title of Professor unless you have a PhD and have been awarded the title by your institution.  So Professor holds considerably more prestige than Dr here.

Comment: Oh yeah, in the US, "Professor" can be used for anyone teaching at the college level, PhD, or not. In fact, a (too) common joke is to say, "I don't hold a PhD, only a Masters degree, so you can call me Master Smith, if you like. If not, then Professor suits me fine."

Comment: To me Prof is much more prestigious.  A full professorship at a university is not easy to get.  At a university you pretty much have to be a PhD and if you have a student doing research work then almost certain to be a PhD.  If they are an associate professor then technically you should use associate as that is the official title.   I think Assoc Prof is more prestigious than PhD.

Comment: I've been to many academic conferences and never seen titles used when people are credited. It's implicit that 99% of the people there either have a PhD or are studying for one so, honestly, writing "John Smith, PhD" is like writing "John Smith, who is more than 25-30 years old."

Answer (score 1):

In my experience at many academic conferences, titles are never used. I've never seen anyone credited as "Dr Smith", "Professor Smith" or anything else involving a title.  Just credit them as "John Smith".  (This is in theoretical computer science; it's possible that other fields differ.)

I don't know for sure what the reason for this is but I would speculate as follows. First, almost everybody at an academic conference either has a PhD or is studying for one. When you're in a room with 50 PhDs and 20 PhD students (and maybe that one guy from industry who doesn't have a PhD), there's not a lot of point drawing attention to who has a PhD and who doesn't.  Second, although one naturally bases opinions on all kinds of things, acknowledging somebody as "Professor Smith" sounds like an appeal to authority: Smith's work should be judged on its intrinsic quality, not on Smith's position on the career ladder. Third, different countries use titles in different ways. In the US, essentially any permanent member of the academic staff is a professor; in the UK, a professorship corresponds roughly to a named chair in the US, i.e., the title applies only to a relatively small number of very senior academics.